# Finding partial matches on strings in R

Tags: regex, r, string, compare

I have a very large database with names like this:

```
names <- c("William Gates", "Bill Gates", "Gates, William H. III", 
    "Gates, William III", "William H Gates", "William H. Gates", 
    "Carlos Slim Helu & family", "Carlos Slim Helu", 
    "Carlos Slim & Family", "Carlos Slim")
```

which I would like to 'clean up' automatically like this:

```
new_names <- c("William Gates", "William Gates", "William Gates", 
    "William Gates", "William Gates", "William Gates", 
    "Carlos Slim Helu & family", "Carlos Slim Helu & family", 
    "Carlos Slim Helu & family", "Carlos Slim Helu & family")
```

where I have (arbitrarily) used the first occurrence of the name to replace other variations of it.

In this example `names` is a character vector of length 10. I would like to create a `10 X 10` matrix of "partial match values". This matrix would store "measures" between 0 and 1 of the extent of the partial match. For instance, comparing `names[1]` with `names[1]` yields a perfect match, so the value would be 1; comparing `names[1]` with `names[2]` would yield something like 5/12 = 0.41667, reflecting the fact that Gates is common to both strings and that (ignoring empty strings) `names[1]` has 12 letters; by the same logic, comparing `names[2]` with `names[1]` would yield something like 5/9 = 0.55556.

I would probably ignore cases (family and Family would be a perfect match) and only focus on matching substrings (but if someone has a comment on how to match, say Slim and Silm, that would be excellent too.

As a second step, I would create a triangular matrix of the maximal values (in the example, the value 5/9 = 0.55556). I would then use this matrix to eye-ball the situation and to select a threshold like 0.95 above which strings are replaced, progressively lowering the threshold until I feel satisfied that the data has been cleaned up.

I expect that this sort of thing has been done before and that someone will be able to help me get started. I have read about Paul Murrell's `compare` package and expect that it would be a great tool to use, but I have not seen too many examples that could be readily adapted, so if you know of a tutorial or of examples other than the package vignette, please do point me to them.

I do realize that more code would be expected of a good question, and I apologize for not being able to provide much. While I am reasonably familiar with R, I am not with string matching. If someone points me to some place to get started, I can then try to rephrase my question with some example code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full answer based on `adist` and clustering.

With arguments `partial=TRUE` and `ignore.case=TRUE`, the function
`adist` from base `R` seems to work with the problem. For the long
haul, the library `stringdist` that Chris S pointed out seems
promising but could also work with this approach.

This solution uses clustering via `hclust`, employing the 'single linkage'
method that takes a 'friends of friends' approach suited
to this problem.

Note that this requires choosing a threshold based on cluster height
(in this case accumulated generalized Levenshtein distance between the
names as viewed through the single-link criterion). If clustering isn't too
expensive for your problem, than visualizing or inspecting the output of
`hclust` shouldn't be too bad either.

```
 ## renamed to avoid overwriting names() function
  raw_names <- c("William Gates", "Bill Gates", "Gates, William H. III", 
      "Gates, William III", "William H Gates", "William H. Gates", 
      "Carlos Slim Helu & family", "Carlos Slim Helu", 
      "Carlos Slim & Family", "Carlos Slim")

 lev_dist <- adist(raw_names, raw_names, partial=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE)

 #use single linkage method as it suits the problem
 hc <- hclust(as.dist(lev_dist), method='single')

 ## cluster vis for picking threshold
 plot(hc, labels=raw_names)
 threshold <- 6 ## in terms of cluster height --

 ## based on threshold, get clusters and make labels
 cluster <- cutree(hc, h=threshold)
 cluster_labels <- sapply(unique(cluster), function(i) raw_names[min(which(cluster == i))])
 (new_names <- cluster_labels[cluster])

 ##  [1] "William Gates" "William Gates" "William Gates"
 ## "Carlos Slim Helu & family" "Carlos Slim Helu & family" [6]
 ## "William Gates" "William Gates" "William Gates"
 ## "Carlos Slim Helu & family" "Carlos Slim Helu & family"
```

Comment: Wow, great! Let me experiment with this tonight (in 8 hours or so) and get back to you with comments. Thanks!

Comment: you forgot to rename names to raw_names, as stated, and it's too small an edit for me to do ;-) I like the dendrogram! must dash off to work, will get back to you asap.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple attempt. just using a built in function and not creating any matrix, but it seems to work on this simple example.

```
names <- c("William Gates", "Bill Gates", "Gates, William H. III", 
           "Gates, William III", "William H Gates", "William H. Gates", 
           "Carlos Slim Helu & family", "Carlos Slim Helu", 
           "Carlos Slim & Family", "Carlos Slim")

new_names <- c("William Gates", "William Gates", "William Gates", 
               "William Gates", "William Gates", "William Gates", 
               "Carlos Slim Helu & family", "Carlos Slim Helu & family", 
               "Carlos Slim Helu & family", "Carlos Slim Helu & family")

nn <- c('Bill Gates','Carlos Slim')


cbind(names, sapply(nn, function(x) 
  ifelse(agrepl(x, names, max.distance = 5), x, NA)))

#      names                       Bill Gates   Carlos Slim  
# [1,] "William Gates"             "Bill Gates" NA           
# [2,] "Bill Gates"                "Bill Gates" NA           
# [3,] "Gates, William H. III"     "Bill Gates" NA           
# [4,] "Gates, William III"        "Bill Gates" NA           
# [5,] "William H Gates"           "Bill Gates" NA           
# [6,] "William H. Gates"          "Bill Gates" NA           
# [7,] "Carlos Slim Helu & family" NA           "Carlos Slim"
# [8,] "Carlos Slim Helu"          NA           "Carlos Slim"
# [9,] "Carlos Slim & Family"      NA           "Carlos Slim"
# [10,] "Carlos Slim"               NA           "Carlos Slim"
```

edit

```
names <- c("William Gates", "Bill Gates", "Gates, William H. III", 
           "Gates, William III", "William H Gates", "William H. Gates", 
           "Carlos Slim Helu & family", "Carlos Slim Helu", 
           "Carlos Slim & Family", "Carlos Slim")

names <- gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', names)
nn <- sort(table(unlist(strsplit(names, ' '))))
nn <- names(nn[nn >= 4])

cbind(names, sapply(nn, function(x) 
  ifelse(agrepl(x, names, max.distance = 1), x, NA)))

#      names                      Carlos   Slim   William   Gates  
# [1,] "William Gates"            NA       NA     "William" "Gates"
# [2,] "Bill Gates"               NA       NA     NA        "Gates"
# [3,] "Gates William H III"      NA       NA     "William" "Gates"
# [4,] "Gates William III"        NA       NA     "William" "Gates"
# [5,] "William H Gates"          NA       NA     "William" "Gates"
# [6,] "William H Gates"          NA       NA     "William" "Gates"
# [7,] "Carlos Slim Helu  family" "Carlos" "Slim" NA        NA     
# [8,] "Carlos Slim Helu"         "Carlos" "Slim" NA        NA     
# [9,] "Carlos Slim  Family"      "Carlos" "Slim" NA        NA     
# [10,] "Carlos Slim"              "Carlos" "Slim" NA        NA
```

Comment: Thanks rawr, the challenge is that all I have to work with is the ``names`` vector. You have created a 'comparison' vector ``nn`` 'by hand'. It's a good start, but while I could use this approach on a dataset of a few hundred names, it will become a challenge for a dataset of thousands such as I have. Your use of  ``sapply``, ``ifelse`` and ``agrepl`` is very useful for me to get started learning about this! thanks.

Comment: Actually, I can subset my data by some criterion like Year and use that as reference vector of strings, so after all your approach should work. I'll need a couple of days to experiment, as I've got a couple of very busy days ahead, but I'll get back to you before the end of the week!

Comment: @PatrickT i see. another option that comes to mind would be sorting out the frequent occurrences of all names and providing some cut-off and using that instead of making the comparison by hand. This is all very basic, of course, I'm pretty basic, see edit

Comment: I saw your edit thanks, let me experiment with this tonight and get back to you, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The stringdist package might help to get the matrix - it's also described in the June 2014 [R journal](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2014-1).  Update: one of the qgram methods may work best for both last, first or first, last names

```
library(stringdist)
stringdistmatrix(names, names, "jaccard")
        [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]   [,5]   [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
 [1,] 0.0000 0.273 0.286 0.167 0.0909 0.1667 0.632 0.562 0.647 0.571
 [2,] 0.2727 0.000 0.467 0.385 0.3333 0.3846 0.684 0.625 0.706 0.643
 [3,] 0.2857 0.467 0.000 0.143 0.2143 0.1429 0.636 0.579 0.714 0.667
 [4,] 0.1667 0.385 0.143 0.000 0.2308 0.2857 0.667 0.611 0.684 0.625
 [5,] 0.0909 0.333 0.214 0.231 0.0000 0.0833 0.579 0.500 0.667 0.600
 ...
```

Comment: Wow, this looks great! Thanks for the reference, I'll probably need a couple of days to digest its content, but this looks very promising indeed!